# Custom View inside Lollipop ViewPager only renders when not visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view

I have built a straightforward, custom `View` class that shows five coloured circles and/or crosses, i.e.:

[image: Custom View Example]

It occupies the top part of a `Fragment`, and acts as a fixed header on top of a `RecyclerView`. The whole thing is placed inside a `ViewPager` alongside one other `Fragment` (there are two `Fragment`s only in the `ViewPager`. This one is the first one).

The problem I am experiencing occurs on my Lollipop device. Whenever the UI loads, regardless of whether it is for the first time or from a config change, this `View` refuses to render. What's very strange though is that if I move my `ViewPager` to the second `Fragment` (so that that the one containing this `View` is no longer visisble) and initiate a config change, when I jump back the `View` is suddenly rendered normally.

I am pretty stumped. I have tried other custom `View` classes in the layout in its place and they all render correctly, so it suggests that something is specifically wrong with my code for this class.

Here is the code for my `View` class:

```
public class HintTrackerView extends View {

private static final int DEFAULT_NO_OF_CIRCLES = 5;

private static final float DEFAULT_RADIUS_PERCENTAGE = 0.9F;

private static final int[] DEFAULT_ACTIVE_COLOURS = {
        PRIMARY_GREEN,
        createInterimColor(PRIMARY_GREEN, PRIMARY_ORANGE, 0.25F),
        createInterimColor(PRIMARY_GREEN, PRIMARY_ORANGE, 0.5F),
        createInterimColor(PRIMARY_GREEN, PRIMARY_ORANGE, 0.75F),
        PRIMARY_ORANGE
};

private static final int DEFAULT_INACTIVE_COLOR = PRIMARY_GREY;

private int[] activeColors;
private int inactiveColor;

private Paint mFillPaint, mInactivePaint;

private RectF mRectF;

private float mFillRadius;
private int mNoOfCircles;

public HintTrackerView(Context context) {
    super(context, null);
    init();
}

public HintTrackerView(Context context, int[] activeColors) {
    super(context, null);
    init(activeColors);
}

public HintTrackerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    init(DEFAULT_ACTIVE_COLOURS);
}

private void init(int[] colors) {
    this.activeColors = colors;
    inactiveColor = DEFAULT_INACTIVE_COLOR;

    if (mFillRadius == 0) mFillRadius = DEFAULT_RADIUS_PERCENTAGE;
    if (mNoOfCircles == 0) mNoOfCircles = DEFAULT_NO_OF_CIRCLES;

    if (colors.length != mNoOfCircles)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number of colours must match number of circles");

    mFillPaint = new Paint();
    mFillPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mFillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mFillPaint.setColor(colors[0]);

    mInactivePaint = new Paint();
    mInactivePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mInactivePaint.setDither(true);
    mInactivePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mInactivePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mInactivePaint.setColor(inactiveColor);

    mRectF = new RectF();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    final int subCanvasSize = getWidth()/ mNoOfCircles;

    for (int i = 0; i < mNoOfCircles; i++) {
        mRectF.set(mRectF.right, 0, mRectF.right + subCanvasSize, getHeight());

        mFillPaint.setColor(activeColors[i]);

        //If hint is has been used, replace symbol with cross
        if (i<3) {
            drawCircle(canvas, mRectF);
        } else {
            drawCross(canvas, mRectF);
        }
    }
}

private void drawCross(Canvas canvas, RectF subCanvasBounds) {

    mInactivePaint.setStrokeWidth(MathUtils.getHypotenuse(Math.min(subCanvasBounds.width(), subCanvasBounds.height()) * 0.1F));

    float innerSubCanvasBounds = Math.min(subCanvasBounds.width(), subCanvasBounds.height());
    float crossLength = MathUtils.getLengthOfFourtyFiveDegreeIsosceles(innerSubCanvasBounds);
    float startX, startY, stopX, stopY;

    startX = subCanvasBounds.centerX() - (crossLength*0.45F);
    startY = subCanvasBounds.centerY() - (crossLength*0.45F);
    stopX = subCanvasBounds.centerX() + (crossLength*0.45F);
    stopY = subCanvasBounds.centerY() + (crossLength*0.45F);

    canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, mInactivePaint);

    startX = subCanvasBounds.centerX() + (crossLength*0.45F);
    startY = subCanvasBounds.centerY() - (crossLength*0.45F);
    stopX = subCanvasBounds.centerX() - (crossLength*0.45F);
    stopY = subCanvasBounds.centerY() + (crossLength*0.45F);

    canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, mInactivePaint);

}

private void drawCircle(Canvas canvas, RectF subCanvasBounds) {

    float centerX, centerY, radius, viewSize;

    centerX = subCanvasBounds.centerX();
    centerY = subCanvasBounds.centerY();
    viewSize = Math.min(getHeight(), subCanvasBounds.width());
    radius = (viewSize/2) * mFillRadius;

    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, mFillPaint);

}
```

}

And the two methods used from my `MathUtils` class:

```
public static float getHypotenuse(float equalLengths) {
    return getHypotenuse(equalLengths, equalLengths);
}

public static float getHypotenuse(float lengthOne, float lengthTwo) {
    return (float) (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lengthOne, 2) + Math.pow(lengthTwo, 2)));
}

public static float getLengthOfFourtyFiveDegreeIsosceles(float hypotenuse) {
    return (float) (0.5F*hypotenuse*Math.sqrt(2));
}
```

Any ideas why this `View` is causing problems?

Comment: Is `onDraw()` being called at all when you are getting the invalid output? If you try viewing the output in Hierarchy View or **`uiautomatorviewer`**, does the `View` render at that point? And if not, is there anything interesting about the view's state uncovered by those tools (e.g., it is positioned off-screen)?

Comment: @CommonsWare `onDraw()` is being called, with the same results for `getWidth()`, `getHeight()`, `radius` etc. whether or not the circles appear. The View is rendered every time in Hierarchy View, but the results don't align with what's on screen. Sometimes it will say the circles have rendered in Hierarchy View when it is offscreen (on page one of the `ViewPager` after a config change) but vanishes when I select page one.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've also since noticed that if I set a background colour then it appears every time. It is just the case that circles and crosses do not appear unless I start a config change whilst my `HintTrackerView` is offscreen.

Comment: I don't work with low-level `Canvas` stuff much, let alone in a `ViewPager`, so I don't really have much in the way of further advice. In fact, this sort of hiccup is one of the reasons why I stick to custom `View` implementations that somebody else wrote. :-) I apologize for not having more to offer you.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for taking a look. Turned out to be something quite mundane in the end!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the fact that `onDraw()` was called twice in certain situations. I was only checking to ensure `onDraw()` was called at all as I mistakenly assumed that every time `onDraw()` was called, the class constructor was called as well. When I added `Log` calls to see how each circle/cross was measuring its boundaries however, I saw this output:

```
10-12 17:53:30.106  13829-13829/? E/TAG﹕ Dimens for rectF:
    left = 115.0
    top = 0
    Right = 230.0
    Bottom = 36
10-12 17:53:30.106  13829-13829/? E/TAG﹕ Dimens for rectF:
    left = 230.0
    top = 0
    Right = 345.0
    Bottom = 36
10-12 17:53:30.106  13829-13829/? E/TAG﹕ Dimens for rectF:
    left = 345.0
    top = 0
    Right = 460.0
    Bottom = 36
10-12 17:53:30.106  13829-13829/? E/TAG﹕ Dimens for rectF:
    left = 460.0
    top = 0
    Right = 575.0
    Bottom = 36
10-12 17:53:30.106  13829-13829/? E/TAG﹕ Dimens for rectF:
    left = 575.0
    top = 0
    Right = 690.0
    Bottom = 36
10-12 17:53:30.106  13829-13829/? E/TAG﹕ onDraw
10-12 17:53:30.344  13829-13829/? E/TAG﹕ Dimens for rectF:
    left = 690.0
    top = 0
    Right = 805.0
    Bottom = 36
10-12 17:53:30.345  13829-13829/? E/TAG﹕ Dimens for rectF:
    left = 805.0
    top = 0
    Right = 920.0
    Bottom = 36
10-12 17:53:30.345  13829-13829/? E/TAG﹕ Dimens for rectF:
    left = 920.0
    top = 0
    Right = 1035.0
    Bottom = 36
10-12 17:53:30.345  13829-13829/? E/TAG﹕ Dimens for rectF:
    left = 1035.0
    top = 0
    Right = 1150.0
    Bottom = 36
10-12 17:53:30.345  13829-13829/? E/TAG﹕ Dimens for rectF:
    left = 1150.0
    top = 0
    Right = 1265.0
    Bottom = 36
```

The `View`'s `width` was `690px`, but when `onDraw` was called for the second time, instead of resetting the values for `mRectF` back to `0`, the previous values were used. This meant that all of the circles/crosses were drawn outside of the boundaries of the `View`.

Adding the following line at the start of `onDraw` and before the `for` loop corrected the problem:

```
mRectF.set(0,0,0,0);
```